# Matplotlib sorts bar chart incorrectly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get a bar chart using Matplotlib in Python 3.6 and although I got the chart, it is not sorted in increasing order.

The code would be able to create a list from a csv file column, count the the occurrences in this list and return a dictionary (occurrences type: occurrences number) and them printing it in a bar chart plot. I can't understand why the bars are not ordered and the examples I saw about this kind of issue are different situation them mine.

The file is not here but the results of print(Dic) are ordered:
Counter({'Walk': 191, 'Sitt': 87, 'CarChild': 28, 'SittCell': 26, 'WalkCell': 23, 'SittTalk': 21, 'Play': 17, 'Shoot': 16, 'PhyExer': 12, 'Jogging': 9, 'PlayFeedF': 7, 'ShootSelf': 6, 'Stand': 4, 'PushPram': 3, 'OnPram': 3, 'ShootCam': 2, 'Portrait': 2, 'Pose': 2, 'PlayFeedB': 2, 'PlayScoot': 2, 'ACTION': 1, 'Sing': 1, 'SittLap': 1, 'SittMag': 1, 'SittBook': 1, 'WalkChild': 1, 'WalkPar': 1, 'PlayInst': 1, 'PlayFeed': 1, 'WalkScoot': 1, 'PlayInstCell': 1})

Here follows the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter


# this block will create a list from a csv column
lista = []

with open('xujiahui.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
for lines in csv_reader:
    lista.append(lines[1])

#print(lista)

# this block will count each item and return a key: value pair dic:
Dic = Counter(lista)
print(Dic)


# this block plots bar chart
uses = list(Dic.keys())
use_num = list(Dic.values())

plt.xlabel('Occurrences')
plt.title('User types and occurrences')

plt.barh(range(len(use_num)), use_num, color='black', tick_label=uses)

plt.show()
```

Here follows the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just discover that the keys and values within both lists are not placed in the same order as the dictionary, therefore the bar are not sorted. So I decided to use a different way to construct both list from the dictionary through a loop and now matplotlib plots correctly. Here is the code and the final plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import collections
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter


# # this block will create a list from a csv column
lista = []
#Count = {}

with open('xujiahui.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        lista.append(lines[1])
#print(lista)

# this block will count each item and return a key: value pair dic:
Dic = Counter(lista)
print(Dic)

mydict = {'walk': 191, 'sitt': 87, 'carchild': 28, 'sittcell': 26, 'walkcell': 23, 'sitttalk': 21, 'play': 17, 'shoot': 16, 'phyexer': 12, 'jogging': 9, 'playfeedf': 7, 'shootself': 6, 'stand': 4, 'pushpram': 3, 'onpram': 3, 'shootcam': 2, 'portrait': 2, 'pose': 2, 'playfeedb': 2, 'playscoot': 2, 'sing': 1, 'sittlap': 1, 'sittmag': 1, 'sittbook': 1, 'walkchild': 1, 'walkpar': 1, 'playinst': 1, 'playfeed': 1, 'walkscoot': 1, 'playinstcell': 1}

# this block generate lists from mydict
use = []
use_num = []
print ('Sort by keys:')
for key in mydict.keys():
    use.append(key)
print(use)

print ('Sort by items:')
for value in mydict.values():
    use_num.append(value)
print(use_num)

# this block will plot
plt.xlabel('Occurences')
plt.title('User types and occurrences')

plt.barh(range(len(use_num)), use_num, color='black', tick_label=use)

plt.show()
```

[image]